# MS SQL Server MAX function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a bit new to MS SQL Server and I am trying to execute a really simple query that goes like:

```
SELECT name, id, description, distance 
FROM my_table
WHERE id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY distance DESC
```

Where my distance values range from 1 to 18752.

For some reason, the above query gives me the top-most distance value as 9999 whereas the values greater than 9999 are found somewhere below.

I also tried getting

```
MAX(distance)
```

which still gives me 9999.

Is there some key aspect of using this function I am missing out?

Comment: is distance an int or something else?

Comment: Is the `id` null for all the values greater than 9999?

Comment: it's possible ditance field is string??

Comment: Yes it was string. Using CAST now for INT sorting. Ty so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is your data type for `distance`.  If it as `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` it is sorting it alphabetically.

If you want it to sort numerically, you would want to use `INT` or something similar.

Comment: +1 Thanks guys. That fixed it. Indeed that was a key point. Added to my sql notes. :)

Answer (score 7):

Your distance is not an int, I presume:

```
SELECT name, id, description,distance
FROM my_table
WHERE id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY CAST(distance AS INT) DESC
```

`CAST` as `INT` it will sort by the integer value.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was getting at with my question.

Comment: +1 . . . I guessing this is right.  But technically, it would be that the int is not *numeric* (or is a character string).

Comment: exactly..that was it...This lead to an important clarification about concepts. +1 all!